# Is it possible to expose a reference type through COM?

Tags: c#, com

I have a dll made by C# and need to call it from an existing native c++ exe.
I have studied the basis of COM and done a simple example.

However, if a C# function has a reference type(especially user-defined class' reference) parameter, can I write an interface for it, and work fine?

I searched in Google but get few information.

**Updated:**
I tried to write one and saw its generated tlh file.
The C# code is

```
void Test2(ref float num);
```

And the generated tlh is

```
HRESULT Test2 ( float * num );
```

The reference type is translated to pointer type. Seems COM is not supporting the reference type.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely can. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/qualifying-net-types-for-interoperation for requirements for COM accessibility and corresponding docs.

Comment: COM strictly works with interfaces under the hood.  But this is hard to get wrong, even if you use the C# class name as the method parameter type then it will still substitute it with an interface.  And even if you did not provide an interface for the C# class then it will automatically generate one.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with reference types.  The `ref` keyword here tells the compiler that the value has to be passed by reference.  So that the function can update the caller's value.  In C done with float*, in C++ done with float* or float&.  Be careful, hard to write correct interop code when essential details like this are still murky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hans mentioned, this question isn't about [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). It's about [passing parameters by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

When you pass parameters by reference *in any language*, you are explicitly or implicitly using a pointer. In C#, `ref` is stating "this parameter will take a pointer to data which has already been initialized." `out` is stating "this parameter will take a pointer to data which may or may not have already been initialized." By using `ref` or `out`, you are shielding yourself from the pointer semantics. That is, you don't have to specify `float*` in the method signature. But rest assured that you're still using pointers.

COM fully supports passing parameters by reference. Here is an example to illustrate.

C#:

```
[Guid("962232c8-90b2-4b61-8ef3-83298901c63e")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ICSCOMCLASS
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void TestInParameter(double num);

    [DispId(2)]
    void TestRefParameter(ref double num);
}
```

After compiling this, you can run `tlbexp.exe` on the resulting assembly to export the COM type library. You can then view the IDL by opening the `.tlb` file in `oleview.exe`.

```
[
    odl,
    uuid(962232C8-90B2-4B61-8EF3-83298901C63E),
    version(1.0),
    dual,
    oleautomation,
    custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "CSCOMLIB.ICSCOMCLASS")    
]
interface ICSCOMCLASS : IDispatch
{
    [id(0x00000001)]
    HRESULT TestInParameter([in] double num);

    [id(0x00000002)]
    HRESULT TestRefParameter([in, out] double* num);
};
```

Note the modifiers on the parameters. As regards your question about `ref` parameters, note that the parameter of the `TestRefParameter()` method is `[in, out] double* num`. This is the equivalent of C#'s `ref double num`.

If you use this assembly or type library from C/C++ (for example, by using a `#import` statement), you'll see something like this:

```
struct ICSCOMCLASS : IDispatch
{
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall TestInParameter(double num) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall TestRefParameter(double* num) = 0;
};
```

COM is designed to work at a C level and up. The majority of the tools that are used for C++ COM work are implemented to use C (not C++) as their baseline for support. Although C++ supports pass-by-reference with `&` (e.g. `HRESULT TestRefParameter(double& num)`, C does not. Moreover, C++'s `&` is not as specific as C#'s `ref` and `out`. (Most modern C++ compilers assume that you want to initialize the data before passing by reference, and they will produce an error or warning if you do not.) Therefore, any parameters defined as `ref` or `out` in the C# definition will be simply defined in C++ as pointers.

Comment: I know the key word `ref` is different with class type so I made a bad example. The thing I want to verify is C# function with a class type parameter. But since I can only get a coclass' instance by COM IF, I think there will be no problem.

Comment: @Holsety `ref` is not different with class types. You're still passing a pointer to the variable data. The equivalent of C#'s `ref IDatabase` is `[in, out] IDatabase**` in IDL and `IDatabase**` in C/C++. The only difference is that an interface implementation in C# is a reference type, so it's inherently `IDatabase*` under the covers. When you pass one of those by reference, it just yields another level of pointer `IDatabase**`.